# easiest way to do the lightening of the image in this example

Tags: jquery, css

A really simple question here. We have some static images and would like make them more interesting. One thing would be to `lighten` them with some type of overlay. For example, mousing over one of the images here:
http://www.cnn.com/interactive/2013/02/world/pope-contenders/index.html (just the lightening effect). What is the easiest strategy to achieve this preferably in jquery?

thx in advance

Comment: you can ask better question than this... please include some relevant code in the question...

Comment: The easiest way would be to __write some code__ that reduces the opacity of the image. Asking here on SO probably won't get you any closer to finishing it if you haven't started yet.

Comment: I'm asking for a proposed idea of how to get this done - i am not looking for specific code; rather whether this could be done in css only, jquery, plugins

Comment: That's a yes or no question... Yes it can be done? If we aren't providing code, this becomes a discussion.

Comment: thx @KevinB - my first thought was opacity but I think a colored overlay is better. opacity assumes a white background to show through

Comment: True, both end up with the same effect in the end. Opacity would be easier in a responsive design, so that you don't have to make the overlay match the size of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put two divs inside each other.

alternatively you can also put a picture `<img/>` inside the container.

```
<div class="img-container">
   <div class="img-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

here's the css you need:
(i assumed all your images have the same heights and widths as in the link you posted. alternatively you can set relative (in %) css properties.)

```
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px; /* your images widths */
  height: 200px; /* your images heights */
  background: url('path/to/your/image.png');
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5; /* it has just to be one more than the one above */
  width: 100px; /* your images widths */
  height: 200px; /* your images heights */
  display: none;
  background-color: '#333333'; /* your color of choice */
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

do it with jQuery:

```
$('.img-container').mouseEnter(function() {
    $(this).children('.img-overlay').fadeIn('fast');
}).mouseLeave(function() {
    $(this).children('.img-overlay').fadeOut('fast');    
});
```

keep in mind that you should use vendor prefixes and filter for IE to make this work in older browsers. ensure also to deactivate it for very old IE and Safari versions.

Comment: Even though the OP marked this as the answer it should be said that you don't "have to put two divs inside of each other". And this solution requires jQuery. IMO why introduce javascript when this is standard behavior that CSS and HTML can execute in a more lightweight manner. Sorry to be a hater, but I just disagree with this approach. @timepone

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with css only

```
.myDiv:hover {
    background-image:url(/path/to/transparent.png); /* width 1px, height 1px, the color and opacity you want*/
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

the problem with opacity is that it wont work in ie7 (maybe also ie8)

Comment: cool, would the background show through the image?

Comment: yes, you just got to save a grafic as .png which is as much  transparent you want. probably the color is white

Comment: on the page you show they did it with opacity thought .myDiv:hover img {opacity:0.4;} but it is not working in ie8 and earlyer

Answer (score 1):

This kind of effect can be easily achievable with css itself.
Try this piece of css.

```
img
{
opacity:1.0;
}
img:hover
{
opacity:0.4;
}
```

For IE8 and later use 
filter:`alpha(opacity=x);`

Answer (score 1):

Opacity won't actually make the hover state "lighter" when applied to the element itself. What you could do is either negative margin or z-index a white div to overlay the img. This way you truly get a **white** fade on hover. Below should serve as a fix to always achieve the "lighten" effect even w/o a white bg.

See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5hy2/)

HTML

```
<h3>Just Opacity</h3>
<a href="#" class="one"><img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/15767501.jpg" /></a>

<h3>With an overlay</h3>
<a href="#" class="two"><img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/15767501.jpg" /></a>
<a class="three">&nbsp;</a>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #262626;
}
h3 {
    color: white;
}
a:hover.one {
    opacity: .5;
}
.two {

}
a.three {
    width: 252px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #FFF;
    display: block;
    margin: -254px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;  
    opacity: .0;
}
a:hover.three {
    opacity: .7;
}
```